# Can't set headers after they are sent.: Sendgrid mail response on Raspbian webserver

Tags: node.js, sendgrid

I am having issues rendering a page after sending an email with sendgrid. 
The problem is most likely in the code snippet below:

```
  sgMail.send(msg, function(err, json) {
if (err) {
  return res.render('contactResponse', 
    {title: 'An error with sending the email has occured. Please try again later or contact me via LinkedIn'});
}

res.render('contactResponse', 
{title: 'Thank you for your email. I will respond as soon as possible.'});
```

});

Now **in localhost this code works perfectly fine**. It renders the "Thank you for your email message and sends me and email.
I then uploaded it to my Raspberry server and started it. Now it gives the following error in the console:
error: 500 - Can't set headers after they are sent. - /contact - POST
And it displays the screen with "An error with sending the email has occured."

Now from other posts I have read, this is probably an issue with res.end being called within a method such as res.render or res.send 2 times. I think it may be an issue here that I am sending a mail, where after I am rendering the response screen. I am not sure if that is the case, it works on localhost so I do not completely understand why it acts strange on my server.

Now I am open to suggestions on how to render a response with "Thank you" or "An error has occurred" without this error. It can also be that something else is the culprit in my code. Please see [this pastebin](https://pastebin.com/7DtP857i) for the full code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple places in your `router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {...}` function that can call `res.render()`, but then execution of the rest of the function continues and thus can call `res.render()` again which is the cause of the "Can't send headers after they are sent" class of error.  You can only send ONE response per request.  After that, Express recognizes that this is an error and logs that particular error message.

So, basically the style of code you're using:

```
if (some condition) {
    return res.render()
} 

// more code here
```

only works until the `if()` is inside some async callback.  Once it is, the `return` only returns from the async callback and doesn't stop the rest of the outer function from executing.  Instead, you will need to nest your `if` statements inside the async callback.

Here's one case where you have the issue:

```
request(verificationUrl, function(error, response, body) {
    body = JSON.parse(body);
    // Success will be true or false depending upon captcha validation.
    if (body.success !== undefined && !body.success) {
        // this return ONLY returns from the request() callback, not from the
        // request handler, thus the rest of the request handler continues to
        // execute
        return res.render('contact', {
            title: "Let's talk!",
            name: req.body.name,
            email: req.body.email,
            subject: req.body.subject,
            content: req.body.content,
            errs: [{
                msg: "Failed captcha verification, try again."
            }]
        });
    }
});

// more code continues here, will allow multiple calls to res.render()
// to happen if the above one got called
```

The `return res.sender()` is INSIDE the `request()` callback so the `return` there does NOT return from the `app.post()`, it only returns from the `request()` callback and then execution of the function body continues.  What you probably need to do is to use more `if/else` and more nesting so that when your code goes down one branch of execution, it doesn't continue down others.

For example, one way to fix this particular occurrence of the problem would be to put an else inside the `request()` handler like this:

```
request(verificationUrl, function(error, response, body) {
    body = JSON.parse(body);
    // Success will be true or false depending upon captcha validation.
    if (body.success !== undefined && !body.success) {
        return res.render('contact', {
            title: "Let's talk!",
            name: req.body.name,
            email: req.body.email,
            subject: req.body.subject,
            content: req.body.content,
            errs: [{
                msg: "Failed captcha verification, try again."
            }]
        });
    } else {
        // rest of function body continues here
    }
});

// no more function body code here
```

> Now in localhost this code works perfectly fine

The logic is clearly wrong.  If it ever works, it's only because you're getting extremely lucky with either asynchronous timing or with a particular flow through your `if` logic that happens to get lucky.  The logic must be fixed to work reliably and repeatedly.